# GRUB that dynamically detects available OSes?

Tags: grub, bootloader, grub2

Is there any version of GRUB that dynamically detects what OSes it can boot on the current disk(s), so that I don't have to run `update-grub` every single time some OS changes on my machine?

Comment: How often do you change OSes?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Often enough that this is becoming an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any GRUB variant which doesn't require some sort of on-disk configuration, but you might want to look into alternatives. I personally use Chameleon ( http://chameleon.osx86.hu/ ), since it is capable of booting OS X, chainloading to the Windows boot manager and multiple linux distributions. It auto-detects on boot.

However, a better fit for your needs would probably be something like the rEFInd Boot Manager ( http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ ), a graphical boot manager with auto-detection of EFI and BIOS boot loaders.